# Rust: error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autorefdue to conflicting requirements in closure

Tags: rust, closures, lifetime

### Raw idea

In a dummy project I have, I would like to use cycling iterators (to generate integers for example).

```rust
use std::iter::Cycle;

type IntegerCycle = Cycle<std::slice::Iter<'static, i32>>;

fn generate_cycles() -> [IntegerCycle; 2] {
  let mut cycles = [
    [1, 2].iter().cycle(),
    [2, 4].iter().cycle(),
  ];

  cycles
}


fn main() {
  let mut cycles = generate_cycles();
  // ...
}
```

### Refactor

Although the previous piece of code works as intended, my real world example is a bit more complicated, so I am looking to adapt the `generate_cycles` function to be able to perform more operations (in the following example, multiply by 2, then generate the cycling iterators).
For this, I tried to use [arraymap](https://crates.io/crates/arraymap):

```rust
extern crate arraymap;

use arraymap::ArrayMap;
use std::iter::Cycle;

type IntegerCycle = Cycle<std::slice::Iter<'static, i32>>;

fn generate_cycles() -> [IntegerCycle; 2] {
  let mut cycles = [
    [1, 2],
    [2, 4],
  ];

  cycles
    .map(|points| {
      points.map(|point| point*2)
    })
    .map(|points| {
      points.iter().cycle()
    })
}


fn main() {
  let mut cycles = generate_cycles();
  // ...
}
```

### The problem

The above solution does not work, and, as a Rust beginner recently exposed to the concept of "lifetime", I do not understand why the compiler is complaining here, or what I can do to make him happy.

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autorefdue to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:20:14
   |
20 |       points.iter().cycle()
   |              ^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #2 defined on the body at 19:10...
  --> src/main.rs:19:10
   |
19 |       .map(|points| {
   |  __________^
20 | |       points.iter().cycle()
21 | |     })
   | |_____^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:20:7
   |
20 |       points.iter().cycle()
   |       ^^^^^^
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
   = note: ...so that the expression is assignable:
           expected [std::iter::Cycle<std::slice::Iter<'static, i32>>; 2]
              found [std::iter::Cycle<std::slice::Iter<'_, i32>>; 2]
```

Here is a REPL with the code trying to make use of the `arraymap`: https://repl.it/repls/ShadowyStrikingFirm .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your type declaration:

```
type IntegerCycle = Cycle<std::slice::Iter<'static, i32>>;
```

You say that you the underlying slices you use to build your iterators must have `'static` lifetime, that is, they must live forever. Then you use literal arrays such as `[1, 2]` that, as all literals, have `'static'`  lifetime and all goes well:

```
let r: &'static [i32; 2] = &[1, 2]; //Ok
```

But then, you try a code similar to this simpler one:

```
let a = [1, 2].map(|x| 2 * x);
let r: &'static [i32; 2] = &a; //error: borrowed value does not live long enough
```

That is the result of `arraymap::map` is a normal array, not a literal one, so it does not have a `'static` lifetime. It cannot be static because you are computing the values in runtime. It will live as long as necessary, in my case as long as the variable `a`.

In your case, since the returns of `arraymap::map` are not assigned to variables, they are temporary values and they are quickly dropped. But even if you assigned it to a local variable, you could not return a reference to it, because the local variable is dropped when the function ends.

The solution is to return an iterator that owns the value. Something like this works:

```
type IntegerCycle = Cycle<std::vec::IntoIter<i32>>;

fn generate_cycles() -> [IntegerCycle; 2] {
  let cycles = [
    [1, 2],
    [2, 4],
  ];
  cycles
    .map(|points| {
      points.map(|point| point*2)
    })
    .map(|points| {
      points.to_vec().into_iter().cycle()
    })
}
```

Unfortunately you have to use a `Vec` instead of an array, because there is not an `IntoIterator` implementation for arrays, (there are for slices, but they do not own the values).

If you want to avoid the extra allocation of `Vec` you can use the `arrayvec` crate that does allow to take an iterator to an array:

```
type IntegerCycle = Cycle<arrayvec::IntoIter<[i32; 2]>>;

fn generate_cycles() -> [IntegerCycle; 2] {
  let cycles = [
    [1, 2],
    [2, 4],
  ];

  cycles
    .map(|points| {
      points.map(|point| point*2)
    })
    .map(|points| {
        let a = arrayvec::ArrayVec::from(*points);
        a.into_iter().cycle()
    })
}
```

**NOTE:** It looks like there is an attempt to add a proper [`IntoIterator` impl for arrays by value](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/65819) to the `std`, but there are still some pending issues.